# How to find Expectation from continuous function with SymPy and Python?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to calculate Expectation and Variance in terms of μ and X, but I do not know what to fill the X below, since it is not a Normal distribution nor Poisson, but a pdf that is random.

```
from sympy import symbols, Integral
from sympy.stats import Normal, Expectation, Variance, Probability

mu = symbols("μ", positive=True)

sigma = symbols("σ", positive=True)

pdf = (15/512)*(x**2)*((4-x)**2)
X = ?

print('Var(X) =',Variance(X).evaluate_integral())

print('E(X-μ) =',Expectation((X - mu)**2).expand())
print('final computation:')
print('E(X-μ) =',Expectation((X - mu)**2).doit())
```

In addition to that, there is another condition `0<x<4`. Thus `E(X)=2` should be the right answer.
[image: 1]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for ContinuousRV?

```py
>>> from sympy.stats import ContinuousRV, P, E
>>> from sympy import Interval, Symbol
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> mu = Symbol('mu', positive=True)
>>> pdf = 15*x**2*(4 - x)**2/512
>>> X = ContinuousRV(x, pdf, Interval(0, 4))
>>> P(And(X>-1,X<1))
53/512
>>> E(X - mu)  # E(X) == Expectation(X).doit()
2 - mu
>>> E((X - mu)**2)
mu**2 - 4*mu + 32/7
```

Comment: Yes, it is the right pdf, I am so sorry I forget to mention there is a limit for `0<x<4` thus the expectation should be `E(X)=2`, how to add this boundary of `x`?

Comment: You can use `X = ContinuousRV(x, pdf, Interval(0, 4))` or otherwise use a `Piecewise` to define the pdf so that it is zero outside that interval. Then `E(X)` and `E(X**2)` will give the expected answers (import `E` from `sympy.stats`)

Comment: @OscarBenjamin , so basically I can get Expectation with these two methods: `print('E(X) =',E(X))` or `Expectation(X).doit()` which one is faster and how to check it?

Comment: (answer updated with @Oscars's additions)

Comment: There is basically no difference between `E(X)` and `Expectation(X).doit()`.